# Set icon of the executable application in Qt

Tags: qt, icons, qt6

The [Qt6 documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/appicon.html) says,

> In order to change the icon of the executable application file itself, as it is presented on the desktop (that is, prior to application launch), it is necessary to employ another, platform-dependent technique.

What are the `platform-dependent technique`s they are talking about?

I am using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) as the build system.

Target platforms: Windows, Mac, Linux (All desktops).

**Clarification:** I am not asking about

> The application icon, typically displayed in the top-left corner of an application's top-level windows

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**:

1. Create a .ico file
2. Add that to your project's source code directory.
3. In your .pro file, add the following: `RC_ICONS = <name_of_your_icon.ico`

**Mac**:

1. Create a .icns file
2. Add that to your project's source code directory.
3. In your .pro file, add the following: `ICON= <name_of_your_icon.icns`

**iOS**:

1. This is easiest set in XCode.
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-app-icon/